# What happens when you plug a BSDF into a value socket?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, mathematics

What happens when you plug a BSDF (shader) socket into a value (float/color/vector) socket, or vice-versa?  Obviously there is no way to convert a function to a value, so what does blender do?

From some simple testing it seems that it converts the BSDF to `0.5`, but sparked by the discussion in comments on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41090/5705) I would like a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't do anything.

Cycles will use the value specified for that socket and ignore the invalid connection:

[image]
<sup>This example uses a color input, but the same applies for value inputs.</sup>

As you can see, the render result is the same with or without the diffuse node in the above setup.

For some explanation on why cycles works like this, see [Convert cycles closure (shader) output to colors?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2229/599)
For a workaround, see [Is it possible to use the output of a Renderlayer in the material nodes of another RenderLayer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2612/599)